# Is there any way to prevent RDP to Windows Server 2003 from auto-locking?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

All my experience RDPing into Windows Server 2008 (albeit not much) has shown that it never locks to the login screen after a period of inactivity, this is really great.

However on Windows Server 2003, if I leave the RDP window out of focus for a certain period of time it locks the screen and makes me type my password. This gets really annoying when I have many different sessions open and need to switch around or I step away from my desk for a moment (I always lock my physical workstation).

Is there any way I can get it to stop locking me out like this so the session just stays keeps the desktop open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

There isn't anything special to this, simply go to your desktop, right click and do `properties` and either disable the screen saver or uncheck `On resume, password protect`

[image]

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thank you sir!

Comment: hehe! When you spend time doing complicated things (guessing you are!) You sometimes just overlook the simple/easy things!