# Windows 11 RDP keeps locking

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

Using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection client (mstsc), I can RDP into a local account on Windows 10 and it will never enter into a locked state, even after hours of direct inactivity. However on Windows 11, the RDP session keeps locking after a minute or so of no direct activity.

[image: Windows 11 RDP lock screen]

I've tried setting the following:

- Turn off `Dynamic lock` (already off because Windows *says* they don't support dynamic lock for remote session. **I wished that was actually the case**).
- Turn off `Screen Saver Settings > On resume, display logon screen`.
- Turn off sleeping the computer when plugged in.
- When plugged in, set screen timeout to something reasonably large (10 minutes).
- Turn off `Personalisation > Lock screen > Advanced slideshow settings > When PC is inactive, show the lock screen instead of turning off the screen`.
- Enabled `gpedit > Computer/Administrative Templates/System/Logon/ > Allow users to select when a password is required when resuming from connected standby`.
- Rebooting the after every attempt above.

[image: Tried settings]

[image: Tried settings 2]

Checked the related questions but they did not help solve the issue:

- Tried as mentioned above: [Is there any way to prevent RDP to Windows Server 2003 from auto-locking?](https://superuser.com/questions/322492/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-rdp-to-windows-server-2003-from-auto-locking)
- No issue keeping session open: [How to keep an RDP session alive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1547184/how-to-keep-an-rdp-session-alive)
- Monitor does not turn off: [Prevent Windows 10 from Locking When Monitor Turns Off](https://superuser.com/questions/1214447/prevent-windows-10-from-locking-when-monitor-turns-off)
- Only using one logged-in user: [How do I prevent lock screen of remote computer when remote RDP connection into the computer is started?](https://superuser.com/questions/1352039/how-do-i-prevent-lock-screen-of-remote-computer-when-remote-rdp-connection-into)

How can I prevent my Windows 11 RDP connection from locking after 1~2 minutes?

- OS: Windows 11 Pro
- Version: 22H2
- Client: Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it had something to do with being unable to properly save screensaver settings.

I followed [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-change-or-save-screen-saver-settings-52b70368-e352-5102-965b-e26f14d1f076) to manipulate the registry and allow my settings to be saved.

Specifically, setting:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"
```

and rebooting the PC made it work.